# Parse server removing object from relation when I adding a object to relation that already exist

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am running open source parse server. I have an table and in the table I have a relation field.

I am adding a new object to relation using `add`

`relation.add(offer);`

But the problem is if offer already exist in relation then this query removing offer from relation instead of add.

Is there any solution?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Are you running MongoDB or Postgres? Do you mind to open an issue to the parse-server GitHub repo with a test case?

Comment: I am running mongodb on heroku (mlab)

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I have created issue here https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6262